# List of freely available online web-developer tools

Tags: list

What **free**, **online** tools does a web developer has at his disposal and "should know about"?

To set the spirit of the list, here are some examples:

- [Google Code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)
- [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)
- [Snipt](http://snipt.org/)
- [CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)
- [Pastie](http://pastie.org/)
- [CodePad](http://codepad.org/)
- [Ideone](http://ideone.com/)
- [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)
- [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)
- [CSSDESK](http://www.cssdesk.com/)
- [Visual jQuery](http://www.visualjquery.com/)

I think a good list could come in very handy for many!

Comment: If the question receives enough edits then it becomes CW, or a mod can make it so. Maybe you should flag it for mod attention and request the CW status?

Comment: @slugster I did this now, thank you! I still find it strange I can't do it myself!

Comment: Thanks @Bil The Lizard for making it CW

Comment: One that I use alot is called the Cloud9 IDE. They have loads of different coding languages and, the one I use the most, is their PHP/Apache2 workspace, which lets you host a webserver (if a free account, only for up to two hours after you last worked on it) to test your website code in a real web environment, complete with your own subdomain for you to visit in a real browser window, instead of a weird test-running window.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst you probably want to automate this on your server, I still find [jscompress.com](http://jscompress.com/) handy to minify or pack scripts.

#### Some others...

- [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/)
- [CSS Border Radius](http://border-radius.com)
- [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.colorzilla.com%2Fgradient-editor%2F&rct=j&q=css%20gradient%20generator&ei=z1n8TNWEHMXzcdfPhfUO&usg=AFQjCNHyieeiVbVLsomqpauRjtztjOVL0w&sig2=1q8r4k-5ZzDGEkyqQtiL6w&cad=rja)

(there are tonnes).

Comment: Border radius is freaking genius! :) I will never be able to remember this!

Answer (score 3):

[Yahoo has a number of good tools](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html).  The YUI material alone is fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

I find [yUML](http://yuml.me/) an invaluable tool to create diagrams online!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've found Chrome's Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to be absolutely indispensable when debugging HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a fantastic tool to spy on (and fiddle with) the traffic your browsers (and other HTTP-connecting applications) are sending.

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com) is great as a HTML/CSS/JavaScript IDE, complete with red sqigglies for syntax errors and intellisense/autocomplete.  (You'll never use Notepad again.)

[jQAPI](http://www.jqapi.com/) is a really zippy version of the jQuery documentation.

Comment: I'm sure firebug has been indispensable.

Comment: Oh and sorry but aptana is not online :)

Comment: @Trufa: but it is free and works on any platform.  I personally prefer my IDE to run locally.  You can do a lot of cool things on the web, but there are some things that are just better as a fat client app.

Comment: Ok I´ll let it go because " it is free and works on any platform" and this is a CW but it was more intended as simpler tools not IDEs but lets just leave it there, it dosnt hurt anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

For PHP development I always use the FREE [phpDesigner 2007 (Personal)](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/downloads.php). It can debug PHP with single step trace and breakpoints. It's also a good editor for CSS, HTML, Javascript, XML etc...

(look under "older downloads" at the bottom).

Comment: I got carried away here :) This is not an online tool, but a free Windows application. It's a little bit old, but it works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

[Bubble](http://bubbl.us/) supports create mind-mapping diagram online. I use it to organize general idea about the application.